# Alternating click binds in jquery - why is the function I'm trying to bind being called?

Tags: jquery, bind

I have a popout that starts off as a bar. There is a circle in the bar. When u click the bar, it popsout. I want to alternate between the circle and the bar being clickable - the circle should close the popout, the bar should open the popout. I cant seem to figure out why I can bind the function dBind normally near the bottom of the code but when I try to bind it within a function, it call's the function I'm binding which ends up defeating the purpose.

```
function circBind(elem){
        var thisDrawer = $(elem).parent();
        var toggleWidth = thisDrawer.width() == 450 ? "25px" : "450px";
        thisDrawer.animate({ width: toggleWidth }).css('overflow', 'visible');
        if (thisDrawer.is("#bottom-drawer")) {
                $
                label = thisDrawer.find('.drawer-label');
                if($(label).is(":visible")){
                }else{
                    $('.search-drawer').bind('click',function(){dBind(this);});
                    $(label).show();
                    var thisPlaylist = $('#site-playlist');
                    $('.playlist-nav').hide();
                    $('.playlist-block').hide();
                    thisPlaylist.hide();    
                }
        }
        if (thisDrawer.is("#top-drawer")) {
                $('.music-list').hide();
                label.hide();
        }
    alert("cc");
    $('.search-circle').unbind('click');
};


function dBind(elem) {
        var thisDrawer = $(elem);
        var toggleWidth = thisDrawer.width() == 450 ? "25px" : "450px";
        thisDrawer.animate({ width: toggleWidth }).css('overflow', 'visible');
        if (thisDrawer.is("#bottom-drawer")) {
                label = thisDrawer.find('.drawer-label');
            if($(label).is(":visible")){
                var thisPlaylist = $('#site-playlist');
                $('.playlist-nav').show();
                $(label).hide();
                thisPlaylist.fadeIn('slow');
                $('.search-circle').bind('click',function(){circBind(this);});
                alert("dc");
            }
        }
        if (thisDrawer.is("#top-drawer")) {
                label = thisDrawer.find('.drawer-label');
                $('.music-list').fadeIn('slow');
                $(label).show();
        }


    $('.search-drawer').unbind('click');
};

$('.search-drawer').bind('click',function(){dBind(this);});
```

Comment: did you check for any error in your firebug console?

Comment: There are two errors that are due to code that isn't this. Would errors from other code cause this? I know errors can act JS to act a lil wonky - I wanted to verify mostly that the fact that it calls the bound function in one part (during cBind) but not when I bind it in other places. Also cBind is not called during dBind... even though I bind it in the same manner

Answer (score 0):

Might be something you already noticed but what's the $ by itself in the circBind function?

Comment: Ah yeah, it is something I noticed and got rid of it but the root of the problem is still there.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind making a jsfiddle of this so I can help you debug?